# Mootools set className

Tags: mootools

I have got a list of events, onClick the elements expand and they SHOULD do the opposite on a second click. That is the part of my little script that does not work. WHY NOT??

```
window.addEvent('load',function() {
  $$('.eventlistitempassive').each(function(item) {
    item.addEvent('click',function() { 
    $$('.eventlistitemactive').set('class', 'eventlistitempassive block');
    item.set('class', 'eventlistitemactive block');
    });
  });
  $$('.eventlistitemactive').each(function(item) {
    item.addEvent('click',function() { 
        item.set('class', 'eventlistitempassive block');
        });
  });
});
```

See the script in action at 
http://hoch3.cc/index.php/aktuelles.html
Thanks,
PB

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
  $$('.eventlistitempassive').addEvent('click', function(){
      this.toggleClass('bar');
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tofu/aUPtw/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is no active element on window.load, so your second selector to add click events on each active item is not finding anything. So try this:

```
window.addEvent('load',function() {
  $$('.eventlistitempassive').each(function(item) {
    item.addEvent('click',function() { 
        $$('.eventlistitemactive').set('class', 'eventlistitempassive block');
        item.set('class', (item.get('class') == 'eventlistitemactive block' ? 'eventlistitempassive block') : 'eventlistitemactive block');
    });
  });
});
```

greatings from austria ;)